# Draw chart for every row of the dataset in SSRS. Loop through dataset rows

Tags: reporting-services

Could anyone help me with how can we create chart for every row of the dataset in SSRS (rdl) !

Suppose the dataset has the following data

Name              Age

-------          -------

A                     25

B                     26

C                     22

3 chart needs to be drawn for the x-axis/y-axis combination of A/25, B/26, C/22. How can I loop through rows of the dataset. And how can I restrict the chart to that particular data point. What would be the xsl expression corresponding to this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a chart in a list control. Group by the dataset fields. and it should repeat